# Doclerizing Vue App throws -error 'sh: dist: uknown operand'

Tags: docker, vue.js

Following the Vue js docker tutorial and I am getting a strange error.

'sh: dist: uknown operand'

my Dockerfile is as below

```
FROM node:lts-alpine

RUN npm install -g http-server

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

copy . .

RUN npm run build

EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ 'http-server', 'dist' ]
```

I have ran my vue build manually and it outputs to /dist directory so all should seem to work?

I am following the basic instructions here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/dockerize-vuejs-app.html

Comment: Not 100% sure but I think you have to use double ticks " instead of single ticks '. Can you check that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's exactly what [Marc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9893114/marc-andr%c3%a9-freiheit) said. Dockerfile CMD should be written with double quotes instead of single quotes.

I have reproduced the whole sequence with webpack template:

```
$ yarn install -g vue-cli
$ vue init webpack my-project
$ cd my-project
$ yarn build

yarn run v1.21.1
$ node build/build.js
Hash: ecbb921d3e4ab8ce9e75
Version: webpack 3.12.0
Time: 5971ms
                                                  Asset       Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
               static/js/vendor.4ad267b4786a3ebd3327.js     121 kB       0  [emitted]  vendor
                  static/js/app.b22ce679862c47a75225.js    11.6 kB       1  [emitted]  app
             static/js/manifest.2ae2e69a05c33dfc65f8.js  857 bytes       2  [emitted]  manifest
    static/css/app.30790115300ab27614ce176899523b62.css  432 bytes       1  [emitted]  app
static/css/app.30790115300ab27614ce176899523b62.css.map  797 bytes          [emitted]  
           static/js/vendor.4ad267b4786a3ebd3327.js.map     613 kB       0  [emitted]  vendor
              static/js/app.b22ce679862c47a75225.js.map    22.2 kB       1  [emitted]  app
         static/js/manifest.2ae2e69a05c33dfc65f8.js.map    4.97 kB       2  [emitted]  manifest
                                             index.html  512 bytes          [emitted]  

  Build complete.

  Tip: built files are meant to be served over an HTTP server.
  Opening index.html over file:// won't work.

Done in 7.69s.
```

Added `Dockerfile` with the next content:

```
FROM node:lts-alpine
RUN npm install -g http-server
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build
EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "http-server", "dist" ]
```

Built the image:

```
$ docker build -t vue-test
```

Build response

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  221.6MB
Step 1/9 : FROM node:lts-alpine
lts-alpine: Pulling from library/node
aad63a933944: Pull complete 
edd41271d385: Pull complete 
dd731a721451: Pull complete 
495807fcdd37: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:6b5b783c9cfe229af0bd5b0b677dd32005bb22d58465f3d0fe7fbd1c60ce068c
Status: Downloaded newer image for node:lts-alpine
 ---> f77abbe89ac1
Step 2/9 : RUN npm install -g http-server
 ---> Running in e61418531b7c
/usr/local/bin/http-server -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/http-server/bin/http-server
/usr/local/bin/hs -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/http-server/bin/http-server
+ http-server@0.12.1
added 26 packages from 35 contributors in 3.847s
Removing intermediate container e61418531b7c
 ---> f593a44b8cf3
Step 3/9 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Running in 84f87785ecbe
Removing intermediate container 84f87785ecbe
 ---> 4db7c4c8281d
Step 4/9 : COPY package*.json ./
 ---> 42468a3d29b0
Step 5/9 : RUN npm install
 ---> Running in c669dca87cbc
npm WARN deprecated extract-text-webpack-plugin@3.0.2: Deprecated. Please use https://github.com/webpack-contrib/mini-css-extract-plugin
npm WARN deprecated browserslist@2.11.3: Browserslist 2 could fail on reading Browserslist >3.0 config used in other tools.
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.11: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated bfj-node4@5.3.1: Switch to the `bfj` package for fixes and new features!
npm WARN deprecated browserslist@1.7.7: Browserslist 2 could fail on reading Browserslist >3.0 config used in other tools.
npm WARN deprecated circular-json@0.3.3: CircularJSON is in maintenance only, flatted is its successor.
npm WARN deprecated mkdirp@0.5.1: Legacy versions of mkdirp are no longer supported. Please update to mkdirp 1.x. (Note that the API surface has changed to use Promises in 1.x.)
npm WARN deprecated json3@3.3.2: Please use the native JSON object instead of JSON 3
npm WARN deprecated socks@1.1.10: If using 2.x branch, please upgrade to at least 2.1.6 to avoid a serious bug with socket data flow and an import issue introduced in 2.1.0
npm WARN deprecated left-pad@1.3.0: use String.prototype.padStart()
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated

> chromedriver@2.46.0 install /app/node_modules/chromedriver
> node install.js

Current existing ChromeDriver binary is unavailable, proceding with download and extraction.
Downloading from file:  https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.46/chromedriver_linux64.zip
Saving to file: /app/node_modules/chromedriver/2.46/chromedriver/chromedriver_linux64.zip
Received 782K...
Received 1566K...
Received 2350K...
Received 3134K...
Received 3918K...
Received 4702K...
Received 5277K total.
Extracting zip contents
Copying to target path /app/node_modules/chromedriver/lib/chromedriver
Fixing file permissions
Done. ChromeDriver binary available at /app/node_modules/chromedriver/lib/chromedriver/chromedriver

> core-js@2.6.11 postinstall /app/node_modules/core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"

Thank you for using core-js ( https://github.com/zloirock/core-js ) for polyfilling JavaScript standard library!

The project needs your help! Please consider supporting of core-js on Open Collective or Patreon: 
> https://opencollective.com/core-js 
> https://www.patreon.com/zloirock 

Also, the author of core-js ( https://github.com/zloirock ) is looking for a good job -)


> uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@0.4.6 postinstall /app/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin
> node lib/post_install.js

npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.2.3 (node_modules/sane/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.12: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN ajv-keywords@2.1.1 requires a peer of ajv@^5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: abbrev@1.1.1 (node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/abbrev):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/app/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/abbrev' -> '/app/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.abbrev.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ansi-regex@2.1.1 (node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/ansi-regex):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/app/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/ansi-regex' -> '/app/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.ansi-regex.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: aproba@1.2.0 (node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/aproba):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/app/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/aproba' -> '/app/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.aproba.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: balanced-match@1.0.0 (node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/balanced-match):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/app/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/balanced-match' -> '/app/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.balanced-match.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: chownr@1.1.4 (node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/chownr):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/app/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/chownr' -> '/app/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.chownr.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: code-point-at@1.1.0 (node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/code-point-at):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/app/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/code-point-at' -> '/app/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.code-point-at.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: concat-map@0.0.1 (node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/concat-map):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/app/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/concat-map' -> '/app/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.concat-map.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: console-control-strings@1.1.0 (node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/console-control-strings):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/app/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/console-control-strings' -> '/app/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.console-control-strings.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: core-util-is@1.0.2 (node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/core-util-is):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/app/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/core-util-is' -> '/app/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.core-util-is.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: deep-extend@0.6.0 (node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/deep-extend):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/app/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/deep-extend' -> '/app/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.deep-extend.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: delegates@1.0.0 (node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/delegates):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/app/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/delegates' -> '/app/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.delegates.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: detect-libc@1.0.3 (node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/detect-libc):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/app/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/detect-libc' -> '/app/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.detect-libc.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fs.realpath@1.0.0 (node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/fs.realpath):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/app/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/fs.realpath' -> '/app/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.fs.realpath.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: has-unicode@2.0.1 (node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/has-unicode):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/app/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/has-unicode' -> '/app/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.has-unicode.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: inherits@2.0.4 (node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/inherits):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/app/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/inherits' -> '/app/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.inherits.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ini@1.3.5 (node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/ini):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/app/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/ini' -> '/app/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.ini.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: isarray@1.0.0 (node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/isarray):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/app/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/isarray' -> '/app/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.isarray.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: minimist@1.2.5 (node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/minimist):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/app/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/minimist' -> '/app/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.minimist.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ms@2.1.2 (node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/ms):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/app/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/ms' -> '/app/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.ms.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: npm-normalize-package-bin@1.0.1 (node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/npm-normalize-package-bin):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/app/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/npm-normalize-package-bin' -> '/app/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.npm-normalize-package-bin.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: number-is-nan@1.0.1 (node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/number-is-nan):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/app/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/number-is-nan' -> '/app/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.number-is-nan.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: object-assign@4.1.1 (node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/object-assign):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/app/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/object-assign' -> '/app/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.object-assign.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: os-homedir@1.0.2 (node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/os-homedir):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/app/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/os-homedir' -> '/app/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.os-homedir.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: os-tmpdir@1.0.2 (node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/os-tmpdir):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/app/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/os-tmpdir' -> '/app/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.os-tmpdir.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: path-is-absolute@1.0.1 (node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/path-is-absolute):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/app/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/path-is-absolute' -> '/app/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.path-is-absolute.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: process-nextick-args@2.0.1 (node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/process-nextick-args):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/app/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/process-nextick-args' -> '/app/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.process-nextick-args.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: safe-buffer@5.1.2 (node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/safe-buffer):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/app/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/safe-buffer' -> '/app/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.safe-buffer.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: safer-buffer@2.1.2 (node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/safer-buffer):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/app/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/safer-buffer' -> '/app/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.safer-buffer.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: sax@1.2.4 (node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/sax):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/app/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/sax' -> '/app/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.sax.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: semver@5.7.1 (node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/semver):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/app/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/semver' -> '/app/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.semver.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: set-blocking@2.0.0 (node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/set-blocking):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/app/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/set-blocking' -> '/app/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.set-blocking.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: signal-exit@3.0.2 (node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/signal-exit):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/app/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/signal-exit' -> '/app/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.signal-exit.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: strip-json-comments@2.0.1 (node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/strip-json-comments):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/app/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/strip-json-comments' -> '/app/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.strip-json-comments.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: util-deprecate@1.0.2 (node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/util-deprecate):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/app/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/util-deprecate' -> '/app/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.util-deprecate.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: wrappy@1.0.2 (node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/wrappy):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/app/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/wrappy' -> '/app/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.wrappy.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: yallist@3.1.1 (node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/yallist):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/app/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/yallist' -> '/app/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.yallist.DELETE'

added 1761 packages from 1107 contributors and audited 32630 packages in 35.045s

28 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 94 vulnerabilities (71 low, 9 moderate, 13 high, 1 critical)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
Removing intermediate container c669dca87cbc
 ---> c62131257405
Step 6/9 : COPY . .
 ---> f99b4dfd6c38
Step 7/9 : RUN npm run build
 ---> Running in 33c0de013074

> my-project@1.0.0 build /app
> node build/build.js

Hash: 411b4ddc717444de54d0
Version: webpack 3.12.0
Time: 5316ms
                                                  Asset       Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
               static/js/vendor.4ad267b4786a3ebd3327.js     121 kB       0  [emitted]  vendor
                  static/js/app.b22ce679862c47a75225.js    11.6 kB       1  [emitted]  app
             static/js/manifest.2ae2e69a05c33dfc65f8.js  857 bytes       2  [emitted]  manifest
    static/css/app.30790115300ab27614ce176899523b62.css  432 bytes       1  [emitted]  app
static/css/app.30790115300ab27614ce176899523b62.css.map  797 bytes          [emitted]  
           static/js/vendor.4ad267b4786a3ebd3327.js.map     613 kB       0  [emitted]  vendor
              static/js/app.b22ce679862c47a75225.js.map    22.2 kB       1  [emitted]  app
         static/js/manifest.2ae2e69a05c33dfc65f8.js.map    4.97 kB       2  [emitted]  manifest
                                             index.html  512 bytes          [emitted]  

  Build complete.

  Tip: built files are meant to be served over an HTTP server.
  Opening index.html over file:// won't work.

Removing intermediate container 33c0de013074
 ---> 1eaff765cd66
Step 8/9 : EXPOSE 8080
 ---> Running in 32a83f985ce5
Removing intermediate container 32a83f985ce5
 ---> 6392c1580a63
Step 9/9 : CMD [ "http-server", "dist" ]
 ---> Running in b4ce812be89c
Removing intermediate container b4ce812be89c
 ---> d5bf5719cf90
Successfully built d5bf5719cf90
Successfully tagged vue-test:latest
```

Started the container:

```
$ docker run -ti -p 8080:8080 --rm vue-test
```

[image: response in browser]

And log in console:

```
Starting up http-server, serving dist
Available on:
  http://127.0.0.1:8080
  http://172.17.0.2:8080
Hit CTRL-C to stop the server
[2020-04-07T22:00:51.235Z]  "GET /" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.163 Safari/537.36"
(node:1) [DEP0066] DeprecationWarning: OutgoingMessage.prototype._headers is deprecated
[2020-04-07T22:00:51.275Z]  "GET /static/css/app.30790115300ab27614ce176899523b62.css" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.163 Safari/537.36"
[2020-04-07T22:00:51.282Z]  "GET /static/js/manifest.2ae2e69a05c33dfc65f8.js" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.163 Safari/537.36"
[2020-04-07T22:00:51.284Z]  "GET /static/js/vendor.4ad267b4786a3ebd3327.js" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.163 Safari/537.36"
[2020-04-07T22:00:51.285Z]  "GET /static/js/app.b22ce679862c47a75225.js" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.163 Safari/537.36"
[2020-04-07T22:00:51.786Z]  "GET /favicon.ico" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.163 Safari/537.36"
[2020-04-07T22:00:51.788Z]  "GET /favicon.ico" Error (404): "Not found"
^Chttp-server stopped.
```

Now I have changed Dockerfile CMD line:

```
CMD [ 'http-server', 'dist' ]
```

Run build:

```
$ docker build -t vue-test .

Sending build context to Docker daemon  221.6MB
Step 1/9 : FROM node:lts-alpine
 ---> f77abbe89ac1
Step 2/9 : RUN npm install -g http-server
 ---> Using cache
 ---> f593a44b8cf3
Step 3/9 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 4db7c4c8281d
Step 4/9 : COPY package*.json ./
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 42468a3d29b0
Step 5/9 : RUN npm install
 ---> Using cache
 ---> c62131257405
Step 6/9 : COPY . .
 ---> 91022384173f
Step 7/9 : RUN npm run build
 ---> Running in 86ee0f134173

> my-project@1.0.0 build /app
> node build/build.js

Hash: 411b4ddc717444de54d0
Version: webpack 3.12.0
Time: 5471ms
                                                  Asset       Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
               static/js/vendor.4ad267b4786a3ebd3327.js     121 kB       0  [emitted]  vendor
                  static/js/app.b22ce679862c47a75225.js    11.6 kB       1  [emitted]  app
             static/js/manifest.2ae2e69a05c33dfc65f8.js  857 bytes       2  [emitted]  manifest
    static/css/app.30790115300ab27614ce176899523b62.css  432 bytes       1  [emitted]  app
static/css/app.30790115300ab27614ce176899523b62.css.map  797 bytes          [emitted]  
           static/js/vendor.4ad267b4786a3ebd3327.js.map     613 kB       0  [emitted]  vendor
              static/js/app.b22ce679862c47a75225.js.map    22.2 kB       1  [emitted]  app
         static/js/manifest.2ae2e69a05c33dfc65f8.js.map    4.97 kB       2  [emitted]  manifest
                                             index.html  512 bytes          [emitted]  

  Build complete.

  Tip: built files are meant to be served over an HTTP server.
  Opening index.html over file:// won't work.

Removing intermediate container 86ee0f134173
 ---> 319528fc6329
Step 8/9 : EXPOSE 8080
 ---> Running in d7c9b4bd106e
Removing intermediate container d7c9b4bd106e
 ---> 04dbc16a3e3e
Step 9/9 : CMD [ 'http-server', 'dist' ]
 ---> Running in a145c39aaea9
Removing intermediate container a145c39aaea9
 ---> 968de870d2df
Successfully built 968de870d2df
Successfully tagged vue-test:latest
```

And if I start container with new image i get:

```
$ docker run -it -p 8080:8080 --rm vue-test

sh: dist: unknown operand
```

So, yeah, you should use double quotes.